# Java: Protect Trial/Demo Period

Tags: java, demo, trial

I searched, and only found a couple([[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146315)][[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769384)]) of answers here.  None of them really answer my question though.

My application will have a thirty day trial period.  What's the best way to protect the program?  I'm not worried about crackers, just Joe Average reinstalling the program.  Setting back the clock isn't really a concern either.

Comment: Can you go into more detail about why the linked solutions don't do what you want?

Comment: Keep in mind that it will be super easy to deompile the .class files and remove the offending code, even if you obfuscate it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent a Demo Java Program from my client's regular use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146315/how-to-prevent-a-demo-java-program-from-my-clients-regular-use)

Comment: @Chris: While that is true, he said he was not concerned with hackers, just everyday people.

Comment: @unholysampler: the first one requires hardcoding the expiration date into the source.  The second has the same problem, and others that require connection to the internet to start up.  I just want to require connection for entering the keys.

Answer (score 3):

Here's exactly the question you're looking for:

[Implementing a 30 day time trial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021088/implementing-a-30-day-time-trial/2022237#2022237)

Comment: I hadn't found that one (was searching under the Java tag).  That answers my question a bit more.  Can you recommend an encryption method?

Comment: where should the file be kept?